# Android app oncliking button update existing map with Geo Coordinates

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, geofire

I have below code for android app that shows selected places on the map
I have added button on the android app
on clicking button I am unable to call particular method in `mainActivity` class that gets GeoCoordinates (GeoFire) and display on the existing map.

So the scenario is, user selects location and Google Maps gets loaded with location and then  click on button that loads GeoCoordinates on the map

Can any expert, guide me with best way of achieving this.

```
private Marker currLocationMarker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "entering onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
 onMapREady()
       {
   }
```

Comment: where is the button click code? and whats is your exact question? you saying best way but where is your way?

Comment: will post full code

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)